# import * best practice in node and react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Should I be importing my node modules using *

example

```
import * from 'express';
import * from './../../myCode';
```

Is it correct that by using the * that all exports will be imported which will make me bring functionality which will increase the file size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, it depends: there is no best practice for import/export since it's very up to you and your use-case. But normally I will just import what I need, not everything. And yes, if you do `import *` the file size of `bundle.js` can be big.

Answer (score 6):

```
import * as myCode from './../../myCode';
```

This inserts myCode into the current scope, containing **all the exports** from the module in the file located in `./../../myCode`.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

    class myComponent extends Component { ... }
```

By Using above syntax your bundler ( e.g : webpack) will still bundle the ENTIRE dependency but since the `Component` module is imported in such a way using `{ }` into the namespace, we can just reference it with `Component`instead of `React.Component`.

For more information you can read [mozilla ES6 module docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).